# Upper bound or approximate form for the CDF of Hypo exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, approximation-theory, stochastic-approximation

The CDF of hypo exponential random variable (sum of $n$ independent exponential random variables $X_{i} $ with different rates $\lambda_{i}$) is given by

[image: CDF of Hypo exponential random variable]

I seek for an upper bound or an approximate form for the CDF to enable me to use it in an optimization problem.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: One approximation is to replace the decreasing sequence of $\lambda$s starting at some index with repetitions of the same $\lambda$.  If we cut off at $2$, for instance, we'd have $1-\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_1 t}(\lambda_2/\lambda_1)^{n-1} - (n-1)\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_2 t}(\lambda_1/\lambda_2)$.  This produces an upper bounding estimate.

Comment: @Eric Towers, Thanks  for your solution. I wonder if we can get an approximate form or upper bound containing all rates $\lambda_{i}$